# Медленно двигается обьект в Unity (плавает прям)

Tags: c#, unity3d

сделал объект наложил риджик на него, и вместо нормального падения с нормальной скоростью, он просто чиллово плавает вдоль экрана (применять силу к нему не нужно, мне нужно чтоб он сам с одной точки упал по физике)

не подскажете, в чем может проблема быть? (пересоздавал сцену и даже юньку перезапустил, помолился богу и прочитал молитву, не помогло)

Comment: а вес установили?

Comment: нет ну я же еще не совсем дурачек, думал рили проблема в нем, поставил 1 000, все такая же беда, гуглил и ничего не нашел
даже на сайте самого юнити читал что-то про риджидбади , но как видите
пришел сюда не просто так

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что были изменены настройки окружающей среды физики. Потому что стандартные настройки не должны иметь такого эфекта. Если создать новый проэкт и новую сцену, создать шар, навесить RigitBody - будет ли падение шара таким же медленным? Может ты изменял настройку "Drag" у RigitBody или еще что?